# ASP.NET - Passing Base64 String From Razor View to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, razor, controller

I am trying to pass a Base64 string generated from an image back to my controller. I have a hidden input field on my view that binds to a property on my view model. However, when I return the view model to my controller, the PhotoPath property shows as null.

[image]

Not sure why the data is not binding. I use Javascript to set the value of the PhotoPath input:

```
      $("#fileChooser").change(function(){
          if (this.files && this.files[0]){
              var reader = new FilerReader();
              reader.onload = function (e) {
                  $("#PhotoPath").val(e.target.result);
              }
              reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
          }
      });
```

This is my input field:

```
    @Html.HiddenFor(d => d.PhotoPath)
```

ViewModel property:

```
    public string PhotoPath { get; set; }
```

If I pass in a regular string in an EditorFor instance, it passes to the controller just fine. Not really sure what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: This is contained inside a template of a Kendo ListView if that provides anymore context.

EDIT 2: This is the inspector after I set the photo:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct value set to the input field with your js code ?

Comment: @Shyju Just added a picture of the inspector after I set the image. It seems to be setting it correctly

Comment: Is your input inside the form being submitted ?

Comment: Try to annotate the PhotoPath view model property as [Required]. I do not get the reason right now, but it has helped me in the past.

Comment: @Shyju Yes, it is being submitted on the Update function of the ListView. If I set the `@Html.HiddenFor` to an `@Html.EditorFor` and just submit a random string, it works just fine

Comment: Is "HttpPostedFileBase" not an option here?

Comment: You should try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046618/get-base64-string-from-image-src).

Comment: @rboe Just tried it and unfortunately had the same result

Comment: can you see the value in the Network tab? look here at the header immediately after you have done the ajax post. this will show if it is truly leaving the client.

Comment: I try your code and its work for me. I think you need to restart your computer and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use @Html or another html helper. Becouse html helpers is work one time(When page load). Because razor is not work after to page load. You should do it with a standart input type: hidden.